# Javascript Find a string between two strings, but keep each occurence of the match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm hoping someone can help. I am new to javascript and been struggling with this task all day. After searching through stack overflow and the rest of google - I'm still unable to solve it.

I have a piece of string:

```
"This is a sentence with a @@DropIn@@ and the sentence is really @@DropIn2@@. I would like to read more sentances because @@DropIn3@@"
```

What I would like to do extract each of the pieces of string inside of the @@ @@. So ideally the script would bring back:

```
Dropin
Dropin2
DropIn3.
```

I have this so far:

```
var tmpD = tmp.match(" @@(.*)@@ ")
```

But this brings back this :

```
"DropIn@@ and the sentence is really @@DropIn2@@. I would like to read more sentances because @@DropIn3"
```

How can I look for each occurrence?

Comment: See [`@@(.*?)@@`](https://regex101.com/r/oE1aA9/1).

Comment: `@@.+?@@`  + instead of * because you want atleast one occrance between @@ and @@ ... and ? so that the pattern is lazy (selects as few characters as possible while matching the pattern)

Comment: "This is a sentence with a @@DropIn@@ and the sente…d like to read more sentances because @@DropIn3@@".match(/@@.+?@@/g)